# WebDav IIS - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: How to allow mulitple values

Tags: iis, cross-domain, webdav

## Context

I am developping a web application and I would like to be able to make cross-domain AJAX requests towards PDF files accessible on a WebDav IIS server.

The domain of my javascript requests are either:

- http://localhost:4200 (When I'm using Angular CLI console)
- http://otherdomain.fr

## My Question

- Is there a way to configure the WeDav server so that it can return a response which *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* contains the request's origin if it is included in a defined set of allowed domains?

## Our attemps so far

The person in charge of the WebDav server tried the following operations in the *HTTP Headers Menu* for header *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* but wihtout success:

- Setting value http://localhost:4200, http://otherdomain.fr

  - Got error: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200,http://otherdomain.fr', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
- Setting value * (To allow any URLs)

  - Got error: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://*' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

## Notes

I read on this page  https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/cross_domain/ :

> Important! Firefox and Chrome require exact domain specification in
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  For servers with authentication,
>   these browsers do not allow "*" in this header. The
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must contain the value of the
>   Origin header passed by the client.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference The server administrator should install this module and properly configure it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.